# Аналог .closest(), только наоборот

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите пожалуйста аналог функции `.closest()`, только чтоб перебор от родителя к ребенку до указанного элемента

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61729/discussion-on-question-by-medvedev--closest--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример на функции `find()`

Первый эл.

```js
$( ".item-a" ).find( "ul:first" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item-a">lalala
    <ul>
      <li>123</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>123</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Последний

```js
$( ".item-a" ).find( "ul:last" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item-a">lalala
    <ul>
      <li>123
          <ul>
      <li>123</li>
    </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>123</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Глубокий

```js
var $deep = $(".item-a").find("ul").children();
var $next = $deep;

while ($next.length) {
  $deep = $next;
  $next = $next.children();
}
$deep.css("color", "red")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item-a">lalala
    <ul>
      <li>123
        <ul>
          <li>123</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>123
        <ul>
          <li>123
            <ul>
              <li>123</li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>123</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: find Найдет **все** вложенные элементы `ul`, `closest` же находит **первого подходящего** родителя

Comment: не так. что будет при вложенности ul? выделятся они все. а надо последний самый глубокий

Comment: @Grundy исправил

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, скорее наоборот, первый самый близкий

Comment: @Duoxx ничего не поменялось. ты не понимаешь суть задачи

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, или ты не понимаешь :-) сейчас что-то похожее на то, что хотел автор

Comment: @Grundy если вложить в li еще ul потом еще li потом еще ul то каков будет результат?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, сейчас выберет самого верхнего ребенка, я проверил :-)

Comment: @Grundy а почему `first` или `last`? вот у нас есть три `ul` на одном уровне и в среднем я добавляю еще ul.... он будет самым глубоким.... а выберется не он

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а откуда у тебя вообще идея что надо самый глубокий выбирать-то? :-)

Comment: @Duoxx Спасибо за быстрый ответ! )) Сам уже стал думать про `find`. Сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: @Grundy не знаю :D щас ченить придумаю)

Comment: С глубоким тоже сделал вариант